# How to set section number 1.1, 2.1, ... 5.1 instead of 0.1 at the start of document

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I am using **report** class. There is no chapter in the document. I am using a custom heading for the section. Since I am not using any chapter hence the section numbers are coming like **0.1 , 0.2**.
But I want the section numbers as **1.1**, for another document **4.1**. Is there any way to start the section numbering from anywhere I want like 1.1, 2.1, 5.1. An MWE is given below

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}[hang]
{\normalsize\bfseries}
{\thesection}
{6pt}
{}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{7pt}{0pt}

\begin{document}
    
    \section{Introduction: quick brown fox}
    A quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog
    
    
    \section{Objective}

\end{document}
```

Comment: \setcounter{chapter}{1}, or 2, or 5.

Comment: write it as an answer. I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: Or, `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}` in order to suppress the chapter number prefix.

Comment: Why you use `report` if you not use chapters in document? Is not then better to use `article`?

Comment: @Zarko it sounds as if the OP is setting each chapter of a larger work as separate documents so not unreasonable to just set `chapter` to 1 if there are no internal cross references between chapters

Comment: @Zarko article gives sections like 1, 2, 3 .... but I need 2.1

Comment: Why, if you not use chapters ...  what sense have number of something what bot exist in your document? Well, this up to you. I will not do tis.

Answer (score 3):

Change the printing of the section number.

```
   % secnumprob2.tex  SE 580955
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{1.\arabic{section}} % one block of sections
\section{First section}
\section{Second}

\renewcommand{\thesection}{4.\arabic{section}} % another block of sections
\section{First section}
\section{Second}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Interpreting the question's reference to "0.1" to indicate section 1, without a chapter, which should become "1.1" or "5.1", *and* that the numbering for ensuing sections should continue "1.2", "1.3" etc, or "5.2", 5.3" and so on; then just set the unused chapter counter to whatever you like:

```
\setcounter{chapter}{5}
```

This document will then fit into some larger work, in the fifth position.

Note that, in case this really is a chapter in document you are producing, you can use `\include` for the chapters, and `\includeonly` to work on one at a time, while having the proper numbering.